# How to manually attach a form field to manytomany model field in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

So this is my function in view:

```
def create_recipe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
           form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               current_user = request.user
               data = form.cleaned_data
               recipe_data=Recipe.objects.create(user=current_user, recipebase_id=data['recipebase_id'], title=data['title'], instructions=data['instructions'])
               recipe_data.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create_recipe'))
           else:
               messages.error(request, "Error")
    return render(request, 'create_recipe.html', {'form': RecipeForm })
```

and here is my form:

```
  class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Recipe
            fields = ('recipebase_id', 'title

', 'instructions')
```

and here is my model:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    recipebase_id = models.ManyToManyField(Recipebase)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    instructions = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**UPDATE**

```
<form action="/create_recipe/" method="post">
{% csrf_token  %}


     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="{{ form.recipebase_id.label }}" class="form-control" >
        <select id="id_{{ form.recipebase_id.name }}" name="{{ form.recipebase_id.name }}">
    {% for value, title in form.recipebase_id.field.choices %}

            <option value="{{ value }}">{{ title }}</option>

        {% endfor %}

          </select>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="{{ form.title.label }}">{{ form.title.label }}:</label>
<input type="{{ form.title.type }}" name="{{ form.title.name }}" max_length="500" class="form-control" id="{{ form.title.id }}">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="{{ form.instructions.label }}">{{ form.instructions.label }}:</label>
<input type="{{ form.instructions.type }}" name="{{ form.instructions.name }}" max_length="500" class="form-control" id="{{ form.instructions.id }}">
</div>


     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When I submit the form, it throws recipebase_id is an invalid argument as:
'recipebase_id' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

It is understandable that it is a manytomany field so it doesnt quite fit like normal text field but I dont really understand which way to put it. Any suggestions?

Comment: `ManyToManyField` should be rendered as multiple choice field so it shouldn't need anything manually. What does it look like in your form? How are you rendering your form? Can you post your backtrace of your error?

Comment: I have updated with the form I am using, if you can point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Comment: Why are you rendering a form manually? Couldn't you use `{{ form.as_p }}` or `{{ form.as_table }}`?

Comment: Because I have to add CSS classes to the fields which are not possible in {{ form.as_p }}

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, but how are you submitting the form? How come your form is not wrapped in `<form>` tag?

Comment: Oh. I didnt post the entire form in question, I will do now.

Comment: Please check it out now @Shang Wang

Answer (score 0):

In the view, you shouldn't save objects like that. You just do this

> obj = form.save()

running the save method on a form creates and saves an object from that form.

Answer (score 0):

you can add class to django form fields in template using django app "django-widget-tweaks" while rendering.
use it in django template to add classes (e.g. bootstrap classes)

e.g. below code adds *form-control* class to input html tag

```html
     {% load widget_tweaks %}
     {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
       {% render_field field class="form-control" %}

      </div>
    {%endfor%}
```

more info on its usage can be found here
https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks